# Using input in the UI component of Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to know if there is a way to use an input in the UI component.

This is my sample code:

```
shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    column(12,fluidRow(column(4, inputPanel(
            selectInput("dx", label = "Diagnosis:",
              choices = DX, selected = "LOW BACK PAIN")
                  ))

    )),
    lapply(unique(allProc[dx.x==input$dx])$pat), function(patient) {
      fluidRow(column(1, tags$p(patient)), 
               column(11, lapply(unique(allProc[pat == patient & dx.x == input$dx])$Clinic), 
                  function(clinic){
                    fluidRow(column(1, tags$p(clinic)),
                             column(10, plotOutput(outputId = paste(patient, clinic), height = "100%")))
                  })))

    })
  ),

  server <- function(input, output) {
    plot 
  )
```

Obviously this is wrong.. I can't just do allProc[dx.x==input$dx]), but the idea is the same. How would I filter in the UI component an element user selects in the same component?

TIA!

Comment: `renderUI` is your friend :)

Comment: can you explain a little more  please?

Comment: You render the dependent UI element in the server based on the other input: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html